# assembly 8086 cursor placement

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, text-cursor

I want to place the cursor after the "paper:" wait until an ENTER is given and then place it after "author(s):". both sentences are defined variables that are printed.

[image]

```
    insert db "******* Insert new paper *******",0,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah, 0Dh, "$"  
    inserttitle db "  Title of paper:      ",0Dh,0Ah,0Ah, "  Name of author(s):     ",0Dh ,"$"
    mainext db ,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,0Ah,"     <<Main>>              <<Next>>","$"

 INSERT NEW PAPER

newpaper proc

    call clrscr

    mov dx, offset insert
    call printf

    mov dx, offset inserttitle
    call printf

    mov dx, offset mainext
    call printf

    call w8click   
    ret

newpaper endp
```

Comment: Can the user enter chars "until an ENTER is given"?

Comment: yes, you're supposed to write the paper title and then the autor's name. after the 2nd enter you are able to either click next or main

Comment: the mouse clicking  is already tested and working, i just can't figure out how to work with the cursor

Comment: The mouse? So you are using the mouse? Ok, do this : when the mouse is clicked, you call my proc `set_cursor` to set the cursor at the mouse position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call next proc to position cursor :

```
;INPUT : DL=X, DH=Y.
set_cursor proc
      mov  ah, 2                  ;◄■■ SERVICE TO SET CURSOR POSITION.
      mov  bh, 0                  ;◄■■ VIDEO PAGE.
      int  10h                    ;◄■■ BIOS SERVICES.
      RET
set_cursor endp
```

Example :

```
call clrscr

mov  dx, offset inserttitle ;◄■■ "  Title of paper:      "
call printf

mov  dl, 18                 ;◄■■ SCREEN COLUMN 18 (X).
mov  dh, 2                  ;◄■■ SCREEN ROW 2 (Y).
call set_cursor             ;◄■■ SET CURSOR POSITION.
```

In previous example cursor will jump to after "paper: ".

**Edit :** two more procs, `cursor_on` and `cursor_off`, to show and hide cursor:

```
cursor_on proc
   mov  ah, 1
   mov  cx, 4          ;◄■■ BIG CURSOR.
   int  10h
   ret
cursor_on endp


cursor_off proc
   mov  ah, 1
   mov  cx, 20h        ;◄■■ NO CURSOR.
   int  10h
   ret
cursor_off endp
```

Comment: @justwarmilk, if you have any question about my proc `set_cursor` just shoot, it's very easy to use.

Comment: i tried exactly that but it doens't show the cursor, don't know if it's a problem with the emulator. what do i need to add to be able to type?

Comment: @justwarmilk, is the cursor totally invisible?

Comment: @justwarmilk, added two more procs to show and hide cursor.

Answer (score 0):

this is a macro that receives the positions X,Y

```
gotoxy macro x y 
    mov ah,02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dl,x
    mov dh,y
    int 10h
    goto endm

; to call it just write: gotoxy 2,4
```